# After assign custom home page layout getting blank page in Magento2

Tags: magento2, layout

Magento2 by default provide 1column, 2columns-left, 2columns-right, 3columns layout and I want to set new layout for my Homepage so I do below process.

First copy 2 files from this path

**1.**  magento2_root ->vendor -> magento -> module-theme -> view ->
    frontend -> **page_layout folder**

**2.**  magento2_root ->vendor -> magento -> module-theme -> view ->
    frontend -> **layouts.xml**

after copy these files I paste these file to below place and change as per my custom layout

**3.**  app -> design -> frontend -> my_vendor -> my_theme -> magento_theme -> **page_layout folder**

**4.**  app -> design -> frontend -> my_vendor -> my_theme -> magento_theme -> **layouts.xml**

in the **page_layout folder** I create new XML file homepage.xml and code for this file is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
<update handle="empty"/>
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
<container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
 <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
 <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
 </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

in the **layouts.xml** file I put below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
<layout id="homepage">
<label translate="true">Home Page</label>
</layout>
</page_layouts>
```

so after done with this files I get `new custom home page layout` in **cms page -> Home page -> design tab - > layout**

[image]

now I go to frontend home page and it shows me blank homepage.below is my homepage image after assign  **custom homepage`**

[image]

when I check the source code for the homepage I show that page is break after body tag and below is my homepage source code.

```
<html lang="en-GB">
<head >
<script>
 var require = {
    "baseUrl": "http://fp.devdemo.in/pub/static/frontend/Forever/theme/en_GB"
};
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="description" content="Default Description"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="Magento, Varien, E-commerce"/>
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<title></title>
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://fp.devdemo.in/pub/static/frontend/Forever/theme/en_GB/mage/calendar.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://fp.devdemo.in/pub/static/frontend/Forever/theme/en_GB/css/styles-m.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://fp.devdemo.in/pub/static/frontend/Forever/theme/en_GB/css/styles.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://fp.devdemo.in/pub/static/frontend/Forever/theme/en_GB/Solwin_FeaturedPro/css/featuredpro.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://fp.devdemo.in/pub/static/frontend/Forever/theme/en_GB/Solwin_FeaturedPro/css/owl.carousel.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://fp.devdemo.in/pub/static/frontend/Forever/theme/en_GB/Solwin_FeaturedPro/css/owl.theme.css" />
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://fp.devdemo.in/pub/static/frontend/Forever/theme/en_GB/requirejs/require.js"></script>
 </head>
<body data-container="body" data-mage-init='{"loaderAjax": {}, "loader": { "icon": "http://fp.devdemo.in/pub/static/frontend/Forever/theme/en_GB/images/loader-2.gif"}}' class="cms-index-index page-layout-homepage">
</body>
</html>
```

so do anyone have any idea?

Comment: You try to remove Layout Update XML `<block class="MageStore .....</block>`? And check any errors in exception log?

Comment: @watson how you fix it ? i am also  stuck on this

Comment: Was this issue resolved? Even I am facing the same issue.